# IOS DEVICE MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel step_detection)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, info-plist

We added a pedometer to our project. We don't have any problem for Android, as version
I'm using pedometer ^2.1.0 and flutter_background_service ^0.0.1+21. We don't get any problem on Android devices, but the error we get on IOS devices => MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel step_detection)

I did a flutter clean, uninstalled the project, reinstalled it, but there was no improvement. I gave the desired permissions in the pedemoter package into the info.plist. Why do you think this happens?

Answer (score 0):

as you have describe your issue this is still open in github

**The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel step_detection:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel step_detection)
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel step_count)**

[Github repo issue for reference](https://github.com/cph-cachet/flutter-plugins/issues/346)